# When does PHP run garbage collection in long running scripts?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

I am writing a PHP cli program that is a worker process for a queue system.

I assumed that PHP collects garbage from time to time in such a case, and won't constantly hit the memory limit.

This appears to not be the case.

### Notes

- Running on PHP 7
- Its a long running script
- `zend.enable_gc = 1`
- There are no global variables

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It comes down to this. You *have* to trigger garbage collection manually by calling `gc_collect_cycles()`.

I have written a bunch of code to try and track this down and come down to two scripts:

This one doesn't crash:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 100;$i++) {
    useMemory();
    gc_collect_cycles();
}
```

And this one crashes:

```
for($i = 0;$i < 100;$i++) {
    useMemory();
}
```

Here is a link to compare these scripts on [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/profiles/compare/5ba470e3-4134-44fa-a839-fd1ef074250d/graph)

As you can see, when you don't call `gc_collect_cycles` it never happens, and you get to the memory limit, and PHP kills itself.

PHP doesn't even use this opportunity to GC itself. The reasoning behind this is discussed on the [PHP-DEV mailing list](http://www.serverphorums.com/read.php?7,1206870), but basically comes down to complications of how to run `__destruct` methods, that require memory, when the memory limit has been reached. (Also on the bug tracker [#60982](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60982)).

Memory usage func:

This is the code I used to 'waste' memory, it purposefully creates cyclic references that can only be cleaned by the garbage collector. Note that without these cycles the objects will be cleaned by reference counting as soon as they fall out of scope.

```
class Big {
    private $data;
    public function __construct($d = 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i< 1024 * 10;$i++) {
            $this->$i = chr(rand(97, 122));
        }
    }
}

function useMemory() {
    $a = new Big();
    $b = new Big();

    $a->b = $b;
    $b->a = $a;
}
```

Comment: The reason you need to call `gc_collect_cyles()` here is because the memory limit is hit before the garbage collector reaches the 10,000 root buffer max used by its cycle collection algorithm.

Each `Big` object is almost 1 MB (on my system) and each iteration adds 2 roots ($a and $b). On about the 64th iteration, 128 roots will exist and a 128 MB memory limit will be exceeded.

If each object were 100X smaller, then 10,000 of them would "fit" in the 128 MB limit and the GC would clear them for you. But large objects in cyclic relationships may require manual calls to `gc_collect_cyles()`.

Comment: @mcfedr I am considering using PHP program to act as a worker/consumer process for RabbitMQ. I would appreciate if you can share your experience. How long it has been running without any issues & did you use systemd or something else to keep it running?

Comment: @MyO Yes, I basically found that you will need something to keep it going, I use supervisord most of the time, but systemd will do the same - also i added some code so that between the jobs coming from the queue, i check there is at least X% of memory left free, and kill the process - the trouble is no php libraries are written to be memory safe, and its hard to keep everything under control as the system grows. btw, really recommend Symfony Messenger component, which can handle a lot of these things for you. https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html